# langchain callbacks StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler strips new line character

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, llama, llama-cpp-python

We were able to get a streaming response from LlamaCpp by using streaming=True and having CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]).
But the issue is the streamed out put does not contain any new line characters which makes the streamed output text appear as a long paragraph.

The content on the console appear right and also when we return the complete response, it contains new line characters. Only the streamed output is the issue.
Due to this we are unable to display the llm output properly.

Tried,

```
def get70BGPULLMObject():
# LANGCHAIN
callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])
llm = LlamaCpp(model_path=llm_model_path,
               temperature=0,
               n_gpu_layers=83,
               n_ctx=4096,
               max_tokens=4096,
               n_batch=2048,
               n_gqa=8,
               verbose=True,
               callback_manager=callback_manager,
               streaming=True,
               stream_prefix=True
               )
return llm

async def generateStreamingOutput(llm, question):
    for item in llm.stream(json.dumps(question), stop=['Question:']):
        yield item
    return EventSourceResponse(generateStreamingOutput(llm, question))
```